Proving that a sequence of expected value is divergent
Let $\{T_x\}_{x\geq 1}$ a "continous" family of discrete random variables, such that $T_x \geq 0$ and $T_x$ pointwisely converges to $T_1$ (in the sense that $\lim_{x\to 1^{+}} T_x(\omega) = T_1(\omega)\quad \forall \omega\in\Omega$). Under the hypothesis that $\mathbb{E}(T_x) = \infty\quad\forall x>1$, what is a sufficient condition such that $\mathbb{E}(T_1) = \infty$?
In my particular case $x \leq y\implies T_x\leq T_y$, so we can not apply monotone convergence theorem (we have the "wrong" sign of inequality). Furthermore none of the $T_x$ for $x > 1$ are in $L^1$ and so we can neither apply the dominated convergence theorem.
An answer could be to check if $T_x\to T_1$ uniformly in $\Omega$, although it's not an easy task in my context (probably it's neither true).
Are there other strategies I'm missing to prove or disprove that $\mathbb{E}(T_1) = \infty$? Of course the simple computation of this expected value in my case is essentially impossible, although I manage to prove that for $x > 1$ is divergent.
I'm asking if, using this fact along with (eventually) other hypothesis, is possible to prove or disprove my claim.
